# Android Dialog with EditText throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview, dialog, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I am trying to make a dialog pop up that displays more information about an entry in a ListView. The ListView is generating fine, and all the variable for the dialog are initialising fine, but when I try to write the relevant description to the EditText box a NullPointerException is thrown. Any ideas?

```
@Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //TODO Add code for action performed on item click here
    // i.e. open dialogue showing details

    // Custom dialog box
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Description: " + savedSubjects[position]);

    // set custom dialog components
    EditText descriptionOutput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogText);
    String descToWrite = savedDescriptions[position]; // I created this in case calling from the array was the problem. In the trace this variable is correctly set.

    descriptionOutput.setText(descToWrite); //the error occurs at this line


    // set dismiss button
    Button dialogButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogButton);
    //if button is clicked close the dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // display the dialog
    dialog.show();
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
EditText descriptionOutput = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogText);
```

instead of

```
EditText descriptionOutput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialogText);
```

to access EditText from dialog layout